# Azure Graph Query

Tags: jquery, azure, graph

I am creating a dashboard using graph query to populate headcount numbers of VMs with the state. (like stopped 23, running 23, etc.)

But not sure how can I write this or if it is possible.

And the second question again belong to Graph query and this is, I want to populate all unattached disk name but not able to achieve this. I can project name, location but not their status.

> where type == "microsoft.compute/disks"
>   | project name, location, (properties.diskState).unattached  // highlighted part is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But not sure how can I write this or if it is possible.

It seems not possible to query the VM state in azure resource graph.

> And the second question again belong to Graph query and this is, I want to populate all unattached disk name but not able to achieve this. I can project name, location but not their status.

Try the query as below, it works fine on my side.

```
where type == "microsoft.compute/disks" and properties.diskState == "Unattached" | project name, location, properties.diskState
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, Sir :)